# How to order by json attribute

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple json file with this:

```
{"Item1": {"p1": {"p1sub1": 8, "p1sub2": 7}, "p2": {"p2sub1": 6, "p2sub2": 5} }, 
"Item2": {"p1": {"p1sub1": 4, "p1sub2": 3}, "p2": {"p2sub1": 2, "p2sub2": 1} } }
```

which I retrieve like this:

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("content2.json")
        .success(function (data) {$scope.items = data;});
});
```

And I show it in my HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(i, val) in items | orderBy:'p1.p1sub1'">
    <li>{{i}} - {{val.p1.p1sub1}} - {{val.p1.p1sub2}} - {{val.p2.p2sub1}} - {{val.p2.p2sub2}}</li>
</ul>
```

I get this, no matter what I put in the "orderBy" filter:

```
Item1 - 8 - 7 - 6 - 5
Item2 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1
```

Is there a way to order the list by the 'p1.p1sub1' values?

**Edit**: What I want is to order the rows with what their p1.subp1 value has in ascendent/descendent order (in this example, p1.p1sub1 is 8 for item1 and 4 for item2), for instance:
Ascendent

```
Item2 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1
Item1 - 8 - 7 - 6 - 5
```

Descendent

```
Item1 - 8 - 7 - 6 - 5
Item2 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1
```

Of course this is only an small sample file. The final file would have many items to be sorted.

Comment: very simple ... javascript objects have no order. Use arrays if you want ordering

Comment: I'm pretty new to javascript. How can I parse the object with the json to arrays?

Comment: do you control the source? If so it might be best to restructure the data there

Comment: I can modify the json file, but what should it look like for it to work properly? I'm so lost here. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: please supply a wanted result.

Comment: I added an edit. I hope it can clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @charlietfl said in the comments, Javascript/JSON objects have no property ordering. Luckily JSON supports arrays which *do* have inherent ordering -- even indexing! Arrays are denoted as comma-separated lists surrounded by brackets, e.g. `["StringA", "StringB", "StringC"]` would create a three item array containing those strings in that order.

Since you said you can change the JSON source, the simplest way to do what you want would be to split out each item into its own object in the array:

```
[
    { 
        "name": "Item1",
        "p1": {"p1sub1": 8, "p1sub2": 7},
        "p2": {"p2sub1": 6, "p2sub2": 5},
    }, {
        "name": "Item2",
        "p1": {"p1sub1": 4, "p1sub2": 3},
        "p2": {"p2sub1": 2, "p2sub2": 1},
    }
]
```

(If you're parsing JSON from a string, don't worry, Javascript's `JSON.parse()` handles arrays without you having to do anything special.)

You could then use the ordering of the array as-is, or use the `orderBy` clause similar to your original attempt:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'p1.p1sub1'">
    <li>{{item.name}} - {{item.p1.p1sub1}} - {{item.p1.p1sub2}} - {{item.p2.p2sub1}} - {{item.p2.p2sub2}}</li>
</ul>
```

But if your actual items use an index-y name scheme, you can even drop the "name" property from the JSON file and use Angular's special `$index` property:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'p1.p1sub1'">
    <li>{{'Item' + $index}} - {{item.p1.p1sub1}} - {{item.p1.p1sub2}} - {{item.p2.p2sub1}} - {{item.p2.p2sub2}}</li>
</ul>
```

Ascendent/descendent order can be controlled by prefixing the 'p1.p1sub1' in the `orderBy` with either a '+' or a '-', e.g. `orderBy:'-p1.p1sub1'` for descending order.

Comment: Thank you! That was a very nice explanation. Now I understand javascript and angularjs a little better. I'll keep studying :)